# Visual Studio 2022 crashes when I create a SSIS package

Tags: ssis, crash, visual-studio-2022

I installed VS 2022, and created a SSIS package for my project. When I create the package, VS 2022 unexpectedly closed several times. Why does this happen?

The error is:

> A previous session ended unexpectedly. Disabling the extension SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022 1.3.2 might help. Disable this extension Manage performance Don't report this extension again

[image]

Comment: I can only suggest the usual troubleshooting steps, assuming you haven't done these: Reboot your PC. Check for extension and/or Visual Studio updates. Uninstall and then reinstall the SQL Server Data Tools extension. Uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall.

Comment: i already did this